# RSpec sequence of returned values AND raised errors from stub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rspec3

I want to stub first two calls to HTTParty with raised exception and then, the third call, should return value.

```
   before do
          allow(HTTParty).to receive(:get).exactly(2).times.with(url).and_raise(HTTParty::Error)
          allow(HTTParty).to receive(:get).with(url).and_return('{}')
        end
```

but one allow override another one. how to set stub to raise errors for first few tries and then let it return a value?

Comment: Take a look at WebMock, especially [Multiple responses using chained `to_return()`, `to_raise()` or `to_timeout` declarations](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#multiple-responses-using-chained-to_return-to_raise-or-to_timeout-declarations)

Comment: @Stefan looks very reasonable! You can turn it into answer :)

Answer (score 10):

According to info provided in [this github issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/736#issuecomment-48549995), you can also do that with the following pure-RSpec approach. It leverages the most general way of **defining mock responses [using block](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.4/rspec-mocks/#label-Setting+Responses)**:

```
before do
  reponse_values = [:raise, :raise, '{}']
  allow(HTTParty).to receive(:get).exactly(3).times.with(url) do
    v = response_values.shift
    v == :raise ? raise(HTTParty::Error) : v
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice! If you set `reponse_values = [nil, nil, '{}']` you can use the neat `response_values.shift || raise(HTTParty::Error)` trick from the GitHub issue.

Comment: That's right! Although I tend to like "explicitness" a bit better in this case.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an array of `Proc` instances to give you complete control:

```rb
my_object = double
values = [proc { raise ArgumentError }, proc { 2 }]

allow(my_object).to receive(:my_method).exactly(:twice) { values.shift.call }

expect { my_object.my_method }.to raise_error ArgumentError
expect(my_object.my_method).to eq 2
```

This way you can raise different exceptions across multiple calls or just return values to suit your needs.

You can use a similar approach to call the original when your stubbed responses have all been used:

```rb
allow(my_object).to receive(:my_method).and_wrap_original do |original, *args|
  values.empty? ? original.call(*args) : values.shift.call
end
```

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case, you could use WebMock:

> [Multiple responses using chained `to_return()`, `to_raise()` or `to_timeout` declarations](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#multiple-responses-using-chained-to_return-to_raise-or-to_timeout-declarations).

Something like this should work:

```
before do
  stub_request(:get, url).
    to_raise(SomeException).then.
    to_raise(SomeException).then.
    to_return(body: '{}')
end
```

`SomeException` should be an actual network error.

Answer (score 1):

I like @b-f approach, but simplified it with `#and_invoke`, and for me, I've already specified the return values, so I just need to know they were both used.

```
allow(my_object).to receive(:my_method).and_invoke(proc { raise ArgumentError }, proc { 2 } )
expect(my_object).to have_received(:my_method).exactly(2).times
```